# NCAlgebra and Simplify, FullSimplify or TensorReduce

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation, ncalgebra

I want to simplify non-commutative expressions calculated using NCAlgebra with commuting coefficients, such as using identities for complex numbers, e.g. having

```
Z*Conjugate[Z]==Abs[Z]^2
```

return

```
True
```

Or having a function that makes use of assumptions, for example assuming an operator to be hermitian

```
$Assumptions=aj[q]==q;
```

such that instances of `aj[q]` simplify to `q`.

I have found no NCAlgebra-specific functions for this. Do functions like `Simplify`, `FullSimplify` or `TensorReduce` interfere with NCAlgebra or do the results remain correct even when used on expressions containing non-commuting factors?

Comment: Have you tried those functions out? That would give you a good sense of what you might be able to accomplish and you could narrow the question down to a specific problem.

Comment: `Z*Conjugate[Z]==Abs[Z]^2//FullSimplify` does evaluate to `True`, but I don't know if standard Mathematica functions not designed for non-commutative algebra hold true when NCAlgebra is used and non-commuting terms are involved.

Comment: All Mathematica functions will operate to simplify your commutative coefficients without problem. NCAlgebra objects are plain Mathematica objects. As for taking into account symmetry and such, we have certain functions that do take into account such assumptions, but not all of them do. Of course you can always apply a rule aj[a]->a which will get rid of all such terms and then simplify.